# Filtering array with Boolean giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter, boolean

I can't understand why the output is 17 its only returning the true values not the false values either that the false value are boolean also

```
function countSheeps() {
  const array1 = [true, true, true, false,
    true, true, true, true,
    true, false, true, false,
    true, false, false, true,
    true, true, true, true,
    false, false, true, true]

  return array1.filter(Boolean).length;
}
```

the output is 17.

Comment: You're filtering out the false values

Answer (score 3):

`Boolean` returns `true` if its argument is truthy and `false` otherwise. `Array#filter` only keeps the values for which the callback returns `true` (or a truthy value). Here, `Boolean` is the callback and since all the values in the array are already booleans, only the `true` values are retained. If you want to keep all values that are primitive booleans, you can use `typeof` in a custom callback function.

```js
const array1 = [true,  true,  true,  false,
    true,  true,  true,  true ,
    true,  false, true,  false,
    true,  false, false, true ,
    true,  true,  true,  true ,
    false, false, true,  true]
console.log(JSON.stringify(array1.filter(Boolean)));
console.log([true, true, false, true, false, 1, "test"]
              .filter(x => typeof x === 'boolean'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.filter()` works by evaluating the return value given to it each iteration. A new array will be returned, but only values/iterations where a truthy value was returned in the block. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Now take a look at what that function `Boolean` does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Essentially, you're passing every value from `array1` to `filter`, and for each of those iterations you're returning the return value from calling that `Boolean` function with the element in question. When you pass `true` to that function, it returns `true`, so that value will end up in the array returned by the `filter` method. When you pass `false`, the Boolean function returns `false` in the block to `filter`, which means the `filter` method will NOT include that value in its return value.

```
console.log(Boolean(true)); // This returns true, so all these values from array1 end up in the final array that filter returns.
```

```
console.log(Boolean(false)); // This returns false, which means for that iteration you're returning a falsey value to the filter method, therefore filter will not keep select/keep the element in question.
```

Answer (score 0):

filter array method : Filters array on the basis of condition provided inside.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
arr.filter(ele => ele>3)
output: Array(3) [ 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Boolean : Boolean returns true if value is true

```
Boolean(true) 
output: true
```

And vice versa

```
Boolean(false) 
output: false
```

Here your checking Boolean(true), in case of true value it is counting but in case of false it is filtering out.
To correct this scenario, Use type checking inside filter function.

```
function countSheeps() {
  const array1 = [true, true, true, false,
    true, true, true, true,
    true, false, true, false,
    true, false, false, true,
    true, true, true, true,
    false, false, true, true]

  return array1.filter(item => typeof(item)==='boolean').length;
}
```